# How to speed up query mongdb with mongoose in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm a newbie in MongoDB and Node.js.

I wrote an example app to measure how fast a get request to MongoDB using Mongoose.

I have a collection with about 200000 records.
In my code, I want to get the first 100000 rows by query:

```
var query = db.myCollection.find().limit(100000);
query.exec(function(err, data){
      // ....
});
```

and it took about 99s, I think that speed was too slow.
Does anyone have ideas on how to speed up the query?

Thank you so much!

Comment: try to create an index for your collection,because Without indexes, MongoDB must perform a collection scan, i.e. scan every document in a collection, to select those documents that match the query statement which increases the response time

Comment: I thought the id is default index in mongoDB.

Comment: Yes, ObjectId is indexed by default with mongo

Comment: @julienBourdic: so you have any approach to increase speed the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mongodb, you can index some of your keys to improve the performance when you're querying. But in this case, this will not work.

Your 99s are probably caused by your PC which just can't handle this kind of heavy load of data in a single time (that's perfectly understandable).

That is absolutely not in correlation with mongodb but with your testing machine memory.

But you maybe can improve it by piping the result :

```
// use our lame formatter
var format = new ArrayFormatter;

// first pipe the querystream to the formatter
myCollection.find().stream().pipe(format);

// then pipe the formatter to the response
// (node 0.4x style pipe non-chaining)
format.pipe(res);

// In node 0.6 we can P.find().stream().pipe(format).pipe(res);
```

With [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/1403797)

Comment: thank you for your help. It's hard to understand and apply to my test.

Comment: I read the gist and really do not understand where data return from db?

Comment: Consider a pipe as a stream. This generate a continuous flow of data from you db into the `res` in this example. I suggest you to learn about `streams` with nodejs. That one of the most important nodejs principle. [This is the implementation on mongoose of the pipe](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/querystream.html)

Comment: I just try to do this:

var start = new Date();
var stream = db.Access.find().limit(100000).stream();
 stream.on('data', function (doc){
  //
 }).on('error', function (err) {
    // handle the error
 }).on('close', function () {
   // the stream is closed
  console.log(new Date().getTime() - start.getTime());
 });

but it still took about 1m30s

Comment: So you won 9 seconds. That's pretty huge for a computer 9 seconds. By dividing, you get more than 1100 results per seconds. That is very great too.

Comment: In fact, that depends of your computer, the size of your documents and the memory allowed to mongoDb. You can also try to increase the memory allowed to Mongod